# Error: ZwAllocateVirtualMemory Failed

Tags: c, memory, malloc

In C when allocating memory,

```
char * undecoded_query_array = (char*) malloc(100);
```

I am receiving the following error:

warning: ZwAllocateVirtualMemory failed c0000018 for heap 006D0000 (base 006D2000, size 0002F000)

Would anyone understand why this is happening? It's quite strange because, I noticed the problem when I changed the command line arguments to my program... When I changed it back to the original argument the program works again??

I also found that if I change the amount I allocate from 100 to 10000, the program works properly again.

Not sure if these findings are relevant or if they relate to the problem at hand.

Thanks.

Comment: The error code `0xC0000018` is `STATUS_CONFLICTING_ADDRESSES`: `{Conflicting Address Range} The specified address range conflicts with the address space.`. For some reason it seems like the CRT is expecting to allocate a particular range of memory, which is really odd. +1

Comment: How are you receiving this warning exactly? Is it a popup window, or is it printed through the debugger somehow?

Comment: I saw the error in the debugger. If I simply run the program, I get a popup window saying my program stopped working properly.

Comment: This is another error forgot to mention: `No source available for "ntdll!RtlRunDecodeUnicodeString() at 0x77b07479"`

Comment: Something is really weird in your system, but I'm not sure what. If you're on Visual Studio, can you copy/paste the entire contents of the Output pane?

Comment: I think this problem was being caused by something I posted in another thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600638/assigning-values-to-2d-array-created-using-malloc). I was using malloc incorrectly prior to the malloc declaration in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that changing your command line arguments has an effect is telling.  My guess is that you are somehow corrupting the `100` that is passed to `malloc`.  How about providing a minimal, complete code sample that demonstrates the problem?  Or you could try passing the size through an `int` variable to confirm that the right amount is being requested.

Comment: My code prior to this is just creating a few arrays using malloc. I tried passing it through an int variable but to no avail... Thanks though.

Comment: Are these just win32 SS outputdebugstrings you're seeing in your debug output pane?  Is the malloc actually succeeding?